# Simulink: can I import 1 x n struct from workspace?

Tags: matlab, struct, user-defined-functions, simulink

I define a struct (say, `input`) in the base workspace, and to avoid a lot of refactoring, I want to import it "From Workspace" to Simulink. I will use it in the Matlab Function block. From what I found (e.g. [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/416565-struct-as-input-to-a-simulink-matlab-function-block)), I need to specify the bus object in the base workspace.

**Attempt 1:**
([from here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/create-bus-objects-programmatically.html))

```
elm(1) = Simulink.BusElement;
elm(2) = Simulink.BusElement;
elm(1).Name = 'a';
elm(2).Name = 'b';
busObj = Simulink.Bus;
busObj.Elements = elm;
input.a = 1.0;
input.b = 2.0;
```

Now, in From Workspace block, I specify `Data: input`, `Output Data Type: Bus: busObj`.
Probably I'm missing something because I get the following error:

> Invalid structure-format variable specified as workspace input in
> 'test/From Workspace'. If the input signal is a bus signal, the
> variable must be a structure of MATLAB timeseries objects. Otherwise,
> the variable must include 'time' and 'signals' fields, and the
> 'signals' field must be a structure with a 'values' field.

**Attempt 2:**

I try to create such a structure of timeseries objects with
`Simulink.SimulationData.createStructOfTimeseries('busObj')` (while `busObj` is defined in workspace), but Matlab complains:

> To construct a MATLAB structure from a bus object, the first argument must be the name of a bus object. The optional second argument can be either a cell array of MATLAB timeseries objects, or a structure of timeseries objects.

**Notes:**

- `input` is a struct of only static parameters, and it's pointless to
  treat it as a time series. Maybe it's possible to "hack" it by
  defining, e.g., a single time stamp and extrapolate these variables as constants?
- It would be best to import `input` as a multidimensional struct, e.g., `1x5 struct with fields: 'a', 'b', ...`, but if it's only possible to have a single dimension, i.e. `1x1 struct`, it's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only I had found out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343304/matlab-from-workspace-block-has-error) earlier...

Since all elements are constant, it's possible to utilize a **Constant Block** and name the variable from the workspace as the "imported" input variable. Next, in Signal Attributes `Output Data Type: Bus: slBus1`, and everything works fine.

The `busObj` can be created manually, but this approach gave me a Simulink compilation error: "some elements in the structure are not correctly aligned with the `busObj`" (I don't know why, everything looked fine). But thankfully this worked:

`Simulink.Bus.createObject(input);`

which created bunch of auxiliary `busObj`s for sub-structures and `slBus1` top-level bus object.